# Handling JSON with escaped characters

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am ITERATIVELY pulling JSON data from the database for some processing and it looks like this:

```
{\"Errors\":{\"Number\":232,\"error\":[{\"errorCode\":\"NS-38\",\"errorDescription\":\"Some Error Desc\"}]}}
```

Now I want to convert this into a python dictionary by using:

```
JSON.loads(json_data)
```

But I get this error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Since I am pulling this from a DB, these strings are treated as RAW STRINGS. Hence the escape chars might cause this issue.

EDIT:
The column I want from DB is stored as VARCHAR. A sample data would be:

```
Headers : 
Content-Type : application/json;charset=UTF-8

Body : 
"{ \"errorStr\" : \"UNAUTHORIZED\" , \"errorDesc\" : \"Request with token absddfsfsdf is a invalid request\"}"
```

I then use regex to get the actual body from above string using {.*}. This part works well.

Then, I send the output of regex match to json.loads() and it fails everytime, giving me all sorts of errors.

Eg. For JSON above (in the edit), I got the foll error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I dont know where the issue is.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, using Python 3.x

Comment: Can you print exact string that you're getting from DB?

Comment: Can you show the code that is fetching the data from the DB? Also, try to print the type of data that you're fetching from the DB.

Comment: Your examples are working fine as I use them.

Comment: What about `replace("\\\"", "\"")`?

Comment: I updated the question to better explain the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the error is caused by the raw string. You can convert it to normal string using:

```py
import codecs
json_string = codecs.decode(json_raw, "unicode_escape")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah this works like a charm. I searched a lot to convert a raw string into a normal string. This ends it. Thanks man !!